# Investing Basics and Recommendations

Tags: investing, brokerage

Suppose an individual has $50,000 in a checking account. He has two brokerage account A and B. Here are some statistics of these two brokerage accounts:

- Account A has total value of $10,000 and a cash equivalent of $300 (trading [EFG](https://www.ishares.com/us/products/239622/ishares-msci-eafe-growth-etf), [RFG](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/RFG/), and [VUG](https://investor.vanguard.com/etf/profile/VUG))
- Account B has a total value of $6,000 and a cash equivalent of $250 (trading [EEM](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/EEM/) and [SLYG](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/SLYG/))

Also, let's assume that this individual has no major expenses (e.g. only food) and the cash flow is about $6,400 per month (before taxes). Here are my questions:

- What is the difference between asset value and cash equivalent? For example, if an individual puts $1,000 from his checking account into Account A, does this increase the total value or cash value?
- How much money should this individual invest in these funds given the above assumptions and how should he choose the funds to invest in? Given the current volatility of the markets, does it make sense to **not** transfer any money from his checking account to either Account A or Account B?

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: @JohnFx: No, it is a real life situation that applies to me. I don't know what to do.